# Hidden field not getting set Ajax AutoCompleteExtender OnClientItemSelected

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to use the following Ajax AutoCompleteExtender:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="300" ID="tbxItem" CssClass="NormalUpper" />
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoCompleteExtenderItemName" runat="server"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServicePath="../Services/AutoCompleteSpecialOrders.asmx"
    ServiceMethod="GetItems" CompletionInterval="100"
    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tbxItem" CompletionSetCount="15" UseContextKey="True" 
    EnableCaching="true" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="True"
    CompletionListCssClass="dbaCompletionList"
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"
    CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList" DelimiterCharacters="">
    OnClientItemSelected="ItemSelected"
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenItemId" />
```

We're using Master Pages (asp.net 4.0), User Controls and UpdatePanels.  I'm having difficulty getting the OnClientItemSelected="ItemSelected" JavaScript/Jquery function to work.  Here is the ScriptManagerProxy:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="../common/script/AutoExtend.js"/>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

And here is the contents of AutoExtend.js (JavaScript & Jquery):

```
//function ItemSelected(sender, eventArgs) {
//    var hdnValueId = "<%= hiddenItemId.ClientID %>";
//    document.getElementById(hdnValueId).value = eventArgs.get_value();
//    alert(hdnValueId.value);
//    document.getElementById("tbxCatalogQty").focus();
// This try didn't work for me}

function ItemSelected(sender, e) {
    var hdnValueId = $get('<%=hiddenItemId.ClientID %>');
    hdnValueId.value = e.get_value();
    alert(hdnValueId.value);
    document.getElementById("tbxCatalogQty").focus();
}  //Neither did this one.
```

The alert DOES show the correct value from our WebService drop-down-type list!  I just can't seem to set the hidden field to this value so I can use it in the code-behind later.  It always shows as "" when run in the debugger.  Also, the .focus() method doesn't set the focus to the tbxCatalogQty field like I would like.  I've also tried this with single-quotes and that didn't change anything either.

In my code behind, I've tried accessing the hidden field as follows without any luck:

```
//var itemId = Request.Form[hiddenItemId.Value];
var itemId = hiddenItemId.Value;
```

I've seen a couple of similar posts out there:  12838552 & 21978130.  I didn't see where they mentioned anything about using Master Pages and User Controls and inside of an UpdatePanel (not sure that makes any difference, however).

Comment: I'm feeling much better about myself if none of you folks know the answer to this problem either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friend, he just figured out the solution.  First, we did a JavaScript postback, passing in the value like this:

```
function ItemSelected(sender, e) {
    var hdnValueId = $get('<%=hiddenItemId.ClientID %>');
    hdnValueId.value = e.get_value();
    window.__doPostBack('UpdatePanelOrdersDetails', hdnValueId.value);
}
```

Then, in the ASP:Panel that contained the AutoCompleteExtender, we added the "Onload="pnlInputCat_Load" parameter.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInputCat" runat="server" OnLoad="pnlInputCat_Load">
```

Then, in the code behind, we added the pnlInputCat_Load method to look like this:

```
protected void pnlInputCat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var theId = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    if (theId != null && !theId.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        Session["ItemCode"] = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        tbxCatalogQty.Focus();      
    }
}
```

There certainly might be better ways to make this work, but I now have the ItemCode in a session variable for later access and I could then set focus on the Catalog Qty textbox.

Thanks for anyone who tried to understand/answer the above question.